# reference for Poincaré constant of $W_0^{1,1}(B)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to figure the optimal Poincaré constant of the space $W_0^{1,1}(B)$, Sobolov space on the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Most paper I found is either about $W_0^{1,2}$ or $W^{1,2}$ with $0$ mean.

Is there any reference for $W_0^{1,1}(B)$ or $W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)$ for a general convex compact domain $\Omega$? Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality On Wikipedia appears a reference to an article about the Poincaré constant for $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ for bounded convex and Lipschitz domains $\Omega$. A unit ball is a convex and Lipschitz domain so It's Poincaré constant is at most $d/2$ where $d$ is the diameter of $\Omega$

Comment: I assume you are referring to the paper by (Acosta & Durán 2004). They only consider the case with $0$ mean. I'm not sure whether the Poincaré constant is the same for the case of $W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This minimizer is equivalent to the first nonlinear eigenvalue of **$\mathbf{1}$-Laplacian**, which is equal to the Cheeger constant of the domain $B$.
The reference is here by B.Kawohl and M.Novaga, which studies the relation between the first non-linear eigenvalues.

*Kawohl, B; Novaga, M*, [**The (p)-Laplace eigenvalue problem as (p\to 1) and Cheeger sets in a Finsler metric**](http://www.heldermann.de/JCA/JCA15/JCA153/jca15043.htm), J. Convex Anal. 15, No. 3, 623-634 (2008). [ZBL1186.35115](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1186.35115)..